# How to get lava in MCPE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Minecraft: Pocket Edition on the iPod, how do you get lava in a bucket in Survival Mode?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes lava waterfalls will spawn in your world like this:
[image: Minecraft Pocket Edition Lavafall]

If your world has one of these lavafalls, you can craft a bucket an collect the lava from the **source block** at the top of the waterfall. Then you will have some lava. If you don't have any lava in your world, then you can't get lava because there currently aren't **cave systems**.

Comment: @Jeffrey_Lin I couldn't add the picture because I am on the mobile interface.